# Add file extension to all files in a folder in R

Tags: r, rename, file-extension

As a result from a loop I have a lot of files without a file extension in a folder.

How could I add a file extension (.png) to all files in the folder while keeping the original name, e.g. from `NAME1` to `NAME1.png`, `NAME3` to `NAME3.png`, `NAME6` to `NAME6.png` etc using R?

Comment: You could add these file extensions in you `for` loop in the first place

Comment: If you have a bash shell its a simple: `for f in * ; do mv "$f" "$f.png" ; done`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `list.files` function you can retrieve the file names under a given path and with a given pattern. From them you can use `paste` to add your file extension and next `file.rename` to rename the files. For instance:

```
    oldNames<-list.files(...) #some argument here
    newNames<-paste(sep="",oldNames,".png")
    for (i in 1:length(oldNames)) file.rename(oldNames[i],newNames[i])
```

Comment: I think everything is vectorised, so no need for a loop: `file.rename(oldNames,paste0(oldNames,".png"))`

Answer (score 1):

Install the `pathological` package and use `replace_extension`.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("pathological", "richierocks")

library(pathological)
old_filenames <- paste0("NAME", 1:6)
new_filenames <- replace_extension(, "png")
file.rename(old_filenames, new_filenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed above could be generalised to allow for changes file extension (in the case below from .xls to .html):

```
path <- "D:/Projects/"

xls_files <- paste(path, list.files(path, pattern = "*.xls"), sep = "")
html_files <- paste(sep="", gsub(".xls", ".html", xls_files))
file.rename(xls_files, html_files)
```