# Importing .xls file that is saved as *.htm, *.html as it is saved on the backend

Tags: r

I have a requirement where I have to import an .xls file which is saved as .*htm, .*html.

[image: FileName]

How do we load this inside R in a data frame. The data is present in Sheet1 starting from Row Number 5. I have been struggling with this by trying to load it using xlsx package and readxl package. But neither of them worked, because the native format of the file is different.

I can't edit and re-save the file manually as .xlsx, as it cannot be automated. 
Also to note, saved it as a .xlsx file and it works fine. But that's not what I need.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. here `temp <- read_excel( "./test.html")` runs fine.. Test.html is a manually renamed test.xlsx-file

Comment: @Wimpel I tried to do a manual import for my file in R. That fails by saying - "Is this an excel file". Also, I tried read_excel, it leaves with a message like this - Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet_i = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : Failed to open

Comment: Excel files are binary files, not HTML. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files, again not HTML. Perhaps you should be looking how to import *HTML tables* instead of Excel files? Or import the actual Excel files?

Comment: @Sid29hard to reproduce without the file itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `openxlsx` package and its function `read.xlsx`. If that doesn't work, you could programmatically rename the file as described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25741965/5224236), and then open it using one of these excel packages.

Your file could be in xls format instead of xlsx, have you tried `read_xls()` function from `readxl`? Or it could also be in text format, in this case `read.table()` or `fread()` from `data.table`should work. The fact that it works after saving the file in xlsx strongly suggests that it is not formatted as an xlsx to begin with.

Hope this helps.